# Template does'nt work with Tailwind in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

If I put the color directly in the tailwind class like `"bg-cianTheme"` it works. But if i use javascript template like `"bg-${primaryColorTheme}"` with the code above doesn't work. Why does it happen and how fix ?

The code:

```js
import { BsGithub, BsLinkedin } from 'react-icons/bs'
export interface INewProfileCardProps {
    photo: string
    github: string
    linkedin: string
    colors: string[]
    primaryColorTheme: string // tailwind refence collor
    secondaryColorTheme: String //tailwind reference collor
    terciaryColorTheme: string //tailwind reference collor
    labelName: string
}

export function NewProfileCard({
    photo,
    github,
    linkedin,
    colors,
    labelName,
}: INewProfileCardProps) {
    const [primaryColorTheme, secondaryColorTheme, terciaryColorTheme] = colors    
    console.log(`bg-${primaryColorTheme}`)
    return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
            <div>{/* <p className="text-[250px]">{'<'}</p> */}</div>
            <div className=" relative h-[202px] w-[404px] rounded-xl bg-whiteIcon px-4 py-8 pt-2">
                <div
                    className={`bg-${primaryColorTheme} relative  flex h-full w-full`}
                >
                    <img
                        className="absolute bottom-0"
                        src={photo}
                        alt="personal-photo"
                    ></img>
                </div>
                <div className="absolute flex">
                    <div
                        className={`flex items-center justify-center font-bold text-${primaryColorTheme} bg-${primaryColorTheme} rounded-l-xl px-6 py-2`}
                    >
                        <BsGithub className="text-2xl" />
                        <p className="ml-3 text-lg">Git Hub</p>
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={` bg-${secondaryColorTheme} ${primaryColorTheme} flex items-center justify-center rounded-r-xl px-6 py-2 font-bold`}
                    >
                        <BsLinkedin className="text-2xl" />
                        <p className="ml-3 text-lg">Linkedin</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {/* <p className="text-[250px]">
                    <span className={`text-${primaryColorTheme}`}>/</span>
                    {'>'}
                </p> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I try to change the colors with variables in tailwind class with template, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the postcss can't find that class when you have interpolated strings like that. You can add this to tailwind.config.js

```
safelist: ["bg-somecolor"]
```

or you can find a way to not use interpolation

Answer (score 0):

In addition to pguardiano's answer, you may be able to achieve the same thing by calling the style attribute directly since postCSS only renders what is readily available in the template...

In your case, you can send the hex code directly to the variable and pass it to the style attribute. Example:

```
<div
className="relative  flex h-full w-full"
style="{{ background: primaryColorThemeColor }}"
>
    <img
        className="absolute bottom-0"
        src={photo}
        alt="personal-photo"
    />
</div>
```

If you want to get your hands dirty and do things in a more interesting way, you can take advantage of Tailwind's theming functionality.

It is explained well in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAtaT8BZEAo.

Then you can update your CSS variables with whatever color is coming from your API I guess. Goodluck hacking your way in :)

Ref:
Updating CSS Variables with Javascript: https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/